# Remove window border in dwm monocle layout

Tags: patch, dwm

I was wondering whether there is some patch to remove the window border in dwm monocle layout, because I really don't want to use "real" fullscreen, but just want to hide the top bar and switch to monocle layout (there is a patch that does that), but then I get these annoying windows borders.

If someone new about a patch that did that, it would be awesome!

Comment: Added link to patch.

Answer (score 2):

There is the noborder patch that removes the boarder when only one window is visible.  https://dwm.suckless.org/patches/noborder/